# Удаление 1 ветки из git, после merge

Tags: git, git-commit, git-merge, git-checkout

Пользуюсь гитом так: под каждую задачу создается отдельная ветка, которая после проверок мержится в master.

И вот возник вопрос, допустим, я смержил несколько веток, но мне понадобилось из мастера убрать одну какую-то старую, но так, чтобы остальные изменения из других коммитов и мерджей в мастере остались. 
Возможно ли это, и если да, то куда копать, посоветуйте?

Comment: Вроде нужно использовать  git rebase

Answer (score 1):

Если же нужный коммит затесался между другими, запускаем rebase:

```
$ git rebase -i HEAD~3

+ pick Add simple benchmarks

+ pick Fix #42: Notifications in IE

+ pick Update docs
```

И просто удаляем ненужную строчку (для нашего примера возьмём самую верхнюю):

```
+ pick Fix #132: one more try
+ pick Update docs
```

Источник: http://tonyganch.com/git/rebase/

Comment: Не делайте так, коллеги у которых вы перепишете историю дадут вам по шапке

Comment: Правильно сделать revert мерж коммита, подход который вы хотите здесь применить не просто неверный, он явно опасный. Чуть ли не единственная опасная штука в гите.

Comment: Делать так как описано по ссылке можно только если вы ничего никуда не отправляли, тем более в мастер.

Comment: @ru_volt а если делать это только в локальной версии, пойдет?

Comment: Да, если только в локальной (фичи которые вы затронули в процессе ребейза есть только у вас), то пойдет. Но в вашем вопросе совсем не понятно, локальные ли это операции, или Вы пытаетесь уже готовую  фичу из мастера убрать. То есть нужно понимать, что ребейз удаляет старые коммиты. И создает, новые. С тем же чейндсетом, но другим хешем. То есть физически другие.